# Android notifications. Динамическое изменение Importance для NotificationChannel не работает

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Я делаю простое приложение у которого есть две кнопки: запустить сервис и остановить сервис.

У приложения есть такие состояния:

- При нажатии на кнопку Start Service запускается Foreground Service и отображается нотификация.
- При нажатии на кнопку Stop Service - сервис.
- При сворачивании приложения, должно отображаться **Heads-Up**(!) уведомление.

Сейчас, при нажатии на Start Service **сразу отображается** Heads-Up уведомление. Но я хочу что бы Heads-Up уведомление отображалось только тогда, когда приложение **уходит в беграунд**.

Я создал флаг *isFirstServiceLaunch*, который говорит, менять Importance канала или нет. Но при этом моя программа не реагирует на эти изменения.

Пожалуйста, можете помочь советом или сказать что я делаю не так? Спасибо!

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallingIndicatorService mService;
    private boolean mBounded;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBounded = false;
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBounded = true;
            CallingIndicatorService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (CallingIndicatorService.LocalBinder)service;
            mService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Show Heads Up notification HERE
        mService.showNotification();
    };

    public void startService(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallingIndicatorService.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent);

        bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND);
    }

    public void stopService(View view) {
        if(mBounded) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBounded = false;
        }
        stopService(new Intent(this, CallingIndicatorService.class));
    }
}
```

*CallingIndicatorService.java*

```
public class CallingIndicatorService extends Service {
    private static final int UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1002;

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private boolean isFirstServiceLaunch = false;

    private IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public CallingIndicatorService getServerInstance() {
            return CallingIndicatorService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startForeground(UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mNotificationManager = null;
        mBinder = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        stopSelf();
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        String name = "my_package_channel";
        String id = "my_package_channel_1";
        String description = "my_package_first_channel";

        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = !isFirstServiceLaunch ? NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE : NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            Log.d("test_t", "importance: " + importance);
            NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                    .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("Title ticker")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle("Title 1")                           // required
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                    .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("Title ticker 1")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(
                            !isFirstServiceLaunch ? Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT : Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH
                    );
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    public void showNotification() {
        isFirstServiceLaunch = true;
        mNotificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вы одина раз создаете канал, не меняя его, если он создан, во-вторых, нельзя priority менять туда сюда. [The importance of an existing channel will only be changed if the new importance is lower than the current value and the user has not altered any settings on this channel.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager) Создайте два канала. ЗЫ Имейте в виду, что для каждого канала пользователь может поменять ваши приоритеты, в соответствии со своими желаниями, в том числе вообще отключить ваши уведомления. Т.о. удалять/создавать каналы не стоит.

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо, ваш совет помог